# homological proof of Gauss identity

Tags: reference-request

In the book [1, p. 54] the authors mention the following identity of Gauss
$$\prod_{n\ge 1}(1-x^n)^3=\sum_{r\ge0}(-1)^r(2r+1)x^{r(r+1)/2}$$
and write

> Several proof are known for the Gauss identity, and they belong to very different parts of mathematics, such as homological algebra, complex analysis, and hyperbolic geometry.

**Question.** Where may I find the "homological algebra" proof of the Gauss identity.

Thanks.

[1] Mathematical Omnibus: Thirty Lectures on Classic Mathematics